# Hook grip but with thumb over middle finger

Tags: grip

I'm trying to the hook grip and I am failing hard, but I noticed something interesting. If I try to do the hook grip as said, but with keeping the thumb on top of the middle finger, I get a pretty strong grip which works better than the normal double overhand grip.

What is this grip called? Is it safe?